# Android view.InflateException Binary XML

Tags: android, xml, inflate-exception

I realize that there are others with similar questions, but I've checked those and this is different.  Also, I had no issues until I recently updated my SDK to Android 4.4, but it didn't seem to happen immediately after.

Here is my error on this Button in my `XML`:

```
  <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnBodyfat"
                    android:layout_width="85dp"
                    android:layout_height="85dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/bodyfat_circle_button"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:text="15%"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
```

Here is my **drawable:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/circle_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bodyfat_circle" android:state_focused="true"></item>
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/bodyfat_circle_disabled" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bodyfat_circle"></item>
</selector>
```

**Logcat:**

```
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.zen.bodybuildingdiet/com.zen.bodybuildingdiet.InitialMainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #55: Error inflating class <unknown>
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
    08-19 20:36:35.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13717):    at       android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
08-19 20:36:35.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13717):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
08-19 20:36:35.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13717):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
08-19 20:36:35.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13717):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
08-19 20:36:35.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13717):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
08-19 20:36:35.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13717):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:269)
08-19 20:36:35.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13717):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1885)
08-19 20:36:35.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13717):    at com.janzen.bodybuildingdiet.InitialMainActivity.onCreate(InitialMainActivity.java:32)
08-19 20:36:35.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13717):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4531)
08-19 20:36:35.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13717):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1071)
08-19 20:36:35.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13717):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2150)
08-19 20:36:35.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13717):    ... 11 more
08-19 20:36:35.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13717): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
08-19 20:36:35.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13717):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
08-19 20:36:35.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13717):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
08-19 20:36:35.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13717):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586)
08-19 20:36:35.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13717):    ... 24 more
08-19 20:36:35.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13717): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: (Heap Size=49187KB, Allocated=43342KB)
08-19 20:36:35.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13717):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreateScaledBitmap(Native Method)
08-19 20:36:35.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13717):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:744)
08-19 20:36:35.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13717):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:766)
08-19 20:36:35.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13717):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:492)
08-19 20:36:35.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13717):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:773)
08-19 20:36:35.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13717):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2051)
08-19 20:36:35.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13717):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
08-19 20:36:35.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13717):    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:119)
08-19 20:36:35.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13717):    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:109)
08-19 20:36:35.912: E/AndroidRuntime(13717):    ... 27 more
08-19 20:36:35.932: E/EmbeddedLogger(1754): App crashed! Process: com.janzen.bodybuildingdiet
08-19 20:36:36.082: E/EmbeddedLogger(1754): App crashed! Package: com.janzen.bodybuildingdiet v41 (2.0.2)
08-19 20:36:36.082: E/EmbeddedLogger(1754): Application Label: BB Diet
08-19 20:36:46.883: E/SurfaceTexture(1611): [Starting com.janzen.bodybuildingdiet] abandon: SurfaceTexture(0x0x1762600) has been abandoned!
```

Comment: What is the full error its giving ?

Comment: I put it right in the the name of post:  Android view.InflateException Binary XML

Comment: That error you quote doesn't explain everything - it normally gives a line number and also the name of the XML file.

Comment: Could you paste your error log?

Comment: Added logcat.  The line # is where the Button starts and that is the xml.

Comment: post complete logcat and xml file, the more information you give us, the more chances you give yourself  for helping !!

Comment: tell us when you edited your file, we wont be informed if you do not!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your error is `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`

you are using a very large image in imageView or background of your button, you should decode it in a proper way , look at 
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/ and 
http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html
those links explain completely how to decode large images and show them on imageViews. for each image that you are using for example for background or capturing photo by camera or .... check the size and be sure it is not large , if it is , this nasty error will come to your app.
(always post complete logcat :-)